# How to convert textfile to different pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

My program gives an output in a .txt file. There are 3 different tables in this output. I need to convert these **three tables** into pandas dataframes. I'm not sure what is the best way to approach this.

This is how my .txt output file looks like:

```
                      column_header standard_content (Old) standard_content (New)
214    STAFF_ORIGIN_IND_NATIVE_AMER                      N                      Y
215    STAFF_ORIGIN_IND_PACIF_ISLND                      N                      Y
128     STUDENT_INFORMATION_RELEASE                      N                      Y
211          STAFF_ORIGIN_IND_ASIAN                      N                      Y
105  STUDENT_ORIGIN_IND_NATIVE_AMER                      N                      Y
104     STUDENT_ORIGIN_IND_HISPANIC                      N                      Y
160       STUDENT_OUTSIDE_CATCHMENT                      N                      Y
346     COURSE_EXTRA_POINT_ELIGIBLE                      N                      Y
528             SUBSTITUTE_REQUIRED                      N                      Y
527        STAFF_ABSENCE_AUTHORIZED                      N                      Y

                     column_header data_req (Old) data_req (New)
20               SCHOOL_SIZE_GROUP              N              Y
241                  STAFF_CONTACT              N              Y
346    COURSE_EXTRA_POINT_ELIGIBLE              N              Y
434   DISCIPLINE_FED_OFFENSE_GROUP              N              Y
32          SCHOOL_ATTENDANCE_TYPE              N              Y
142       STUDENT_COUNTRY_OF_BIRTH              N              Y
74            FACILITY_COUNTY_CODE              N              Y
64         FACILITY_PARKING_SPACES              N              Y
436  DISCIPLINE_DIST_OFFENSE_GROUP              N              Y
321          STAFF_BARGAINING_UNIT              N              Y

                   column_header element_type (Old) element_type (New)
331                DISTRICT_CODE                Key              Local
511                DISTRICT_CODE                Key              Local
445                DISTRICT_CODE                Key              Local
2                  DISTRICT_CODE                Key              Local
302  STAFF_ASSIGN_FINANCIAL_CODE                Key              Local
493            SCHEDULE_SEQUENCE                Key              Local
461                  INCIDENT_ID                Key              Local
431                  INCIDENT_ID                Key              Local
159       STUDENT_CATCHMENT_CODE                Key              Local
393                DISTRICT_CODE                Key              Local
```

I tried to use this in a loop but it creates a **single** dataframe and it gets messed up.

```
   df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(report)
             df.to_csv('data.csv')
             result_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', )
             print("Final report", result_df)
```

Is there a way I can create a new dataframe based on a keyword, for example 'column_header', or any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in few steps.

- Slurp the entire file
- split according to a delimiter (empty lines)
- read each part into a separate dataframe

if we let `RAW_DATA` be the content of your file, this could be done with

```
  dfs = [pd.read_fwf(StringIO(part), 
                      header=None, skiprows=1, 
                      names=['id', 'header', 'old', 'new']) 
         for part in raw_data.strip().split('\n\n')]
```

The split looks for empty lines.  The read_fwf call uses several pandas TextParser [options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html) to skip the header row and explicitly name the columns(the actual column headers throw off the fixed width parser).

The first frame will look like

```
    id                          header old new
0  214    STAFF_ORIGIN_IND_NATIVE_AMER   N   Y
1  215    STAFF_ORIGIN_IND_PACIF_ISLND   N   Y
2  128     STUDENT_INFORMATION_RELEASE   N   Y
3  211          STAFF_ORIGIN_IND_ASIAN   N   Y
4  105  STUDENT_ORIGIN_IND_NATIVE_AMER   N   Y
5  104     STUDENT_ORIGIN_IND_HISPANIC   N   Y
6  160       STUDENT_OUTSIDE_CATCHMENT   N   Y
7  346     COURSE_EXTRA_POINT_ELIGIBLE   N   Y
8  528             SUBSTITUTE_REQUIRED   N   Y
9  527        STAFF_ABSENCE_AUTHORIZED   N   Y
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this but it gave me the following error:  

`raise EmptyDataError("No rows from which to infer column width")
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No rows from which to infer column width`

Comment: I'm guessing that it is because there is an extra blank line at the end of your file.  Try adding the strip() before the split (see updated answer).

Comment: I actually have 3 blank lines at the end of my file. I tried the new code but it's giving me the same error again. Not sure what to change.

Comment: Try looking at the result of `raw_data.strip().split('\n\n')`  Perhaps you need a different delimiter.